# How to view Mercurial changeset changes using a GUI diff tool

Tags: mercurial, windows-xp, diff, examdiff

We use both Examdiff and Kdiff3 to view Mercurial changes.

Just add this to `.hgrc`:

```
[extdiff]
cmd.kdiff3 =
cmd.examdiff = C:\Program Files\ExamDiff Pro\ExamDiff.exe
```

And then you can type `hg examdiff` or `hg diff3` to see a complete diff of all your changes.

What I would like is to do the same to see a "before and after" of files for a given changeset that was checked in by someone else.

I know you can type `hg log` to see all changesets and then `hg log -vprXX` to see a text diff, but that's too hard for my GUI preferring eyes.  Anyone know how to the equivalent with the GUI tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't use just use the `-c` option to extdiff?

```
hg kdiff3 -c XX
```

or

```
hg examdiff -c XX
```

in your example?

> -c --change   change made by revision

from the `hg help extdiff` output.