# Diff current source vs source at point in time

Tags: mercurial, diff, examdiff

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580662/how-to-view-mercurial-changeset-changes-using-a-gui-diff-tool) how to view all changes in a changeset..

But let's say you update your source, you do a `pull` and you get 3 new changesets.  How can you compare the current state of the remote repository (with the 3 changesets checked in) vs. the current source (on your local machine)?

I'd like to do this using the visual diff tool which I currently have configured (Examdiff or Kdiff3).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to compare the current working directory with the `tip` revision, so you should be able to use `hg diff -r tip`.

Comment: Thanks.  Although different from my question, how about if you want to compare the working directory with the remote repository as of a given date?

Comment: You can use `hg log -l 1 -d {date}` to get the revision number on said date (use `hg help dates` for date formats), then specify the revision number when running `hg diff`. For example, if you see `changeset: 93:e38f8c404758`, you then run `hg diff -r 93`. This will only give you the revisions committed on a certain date though, not the revision *as of* that date, so its functionality is limited, but it should help.